Incorrect receipt size when printing to thermal printer
I've been tasked of creating custom receipts with logos that can be dynamically generated.
So I've used html / css for creating templates and chrome in headless mode (puppeteer) to generate pdf (or alternatively images), of the receipt.
The issue I'm having is that when I try to print a pdf which has the correct size of the ticket, either:

I set the page size of the printer and the receipt is cut in half
I don't set the page size and the printer keeps printing a blank receipt that does not stop until I turn it off.

Not sure where to look from there.

Your question does not include any concrete facts (printer vendor, model number and its command specifications), numbers, program source, or a dump of the data sent, so it will be difficult to get advice or answers. No one can determine how your printing program processes the data, what kind of print data it sends, or what the result is. Please refer to this help article to improve your question. How do I ask a good question?, How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
